# How to shrink the disk of a LXC container on Proxmox 4?

Tags: lxc, proxmox

I would like to shrink the main disk of a LXC container on a Proxmox VE 4.2, from 30GB to 20GB for instance. Shrinking seems not to be supported yet :

```
$ pct resize <VMID> rootfs 20G
unable to shrink disk size
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably figured it out already, but that seems to be a limitation of LXC containers, at least for now. From the pct man page :

```
 <size> \+?\d+(\.\d+)?[KMGT]?
       The new size. With the + sign the value is added to the actual size of the volume and without it,
       the value is taken as an absolute one. Shrinking disk size is not supported.
```

If you truly want to shrink a container, I guess you'd have to perform a backup, then restore it with the `--rootfs local:<newsize>` option, like so :

```
pct stop <id>
vzdump <id> -storage local -compress lzo
pct destroy <id>
pct restore <id> /var/lib/lxc/vzdump-lxc-<id>-....tar.lzo --rootfs local:<newsize>
```

Of course, you can't perform this sort of resizing online, so I wouldn't call it a great solution, but it works if you have no other choice.

Good luck,

Comment: I have used zerofree to determine on many data can be saved, used it on a raw image of a stopped container... but it still miss shrinking. As virtualbox can do with: "VBoxManage modifyhd --compact disk.vdi"

Comment: found it : you can use "fallocate -v  --dig-holes /.../file.raw"

Comment: Thank you it worked, but with Proxmox 5 I had to use this syntax to resize the image to 40G: `--rootfs 40`

Comment: You may as well want to append `-unprivileged`

Comment: Ok for Proxmox 5.4-13 using  --rootfs local:30

Comment: Warning! DO NOT ``` pct destroy <id>
``` when you atteched a volume mount disk. In this case your data / disk is gone. Proxmox only say "delete uses data". But deleting mount points is fail in design.

Answer (score 3):

This is now much easier and can be done without backup and restore.

```
root@pve:~# lvdisplay | grep "LV Path\|LV Size"
  LV Path                /dev/pve/swap
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  LV Path                /dev/pve/root
  LV Size                96.00 GiB
  LV Size                1.67 TiB
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-100-disk-0
  LV Size                40.00 GiB
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-101-disk-0
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0
  LV Size                508.00 GiB
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-104-disk-0
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-105-disk-0
  LV Size                1000.00 GiB
  LV Path                /dev/pve/snap_vm-105-disk-0_vzdump
  LV Size                500.00 GiB
root@pve:~# e2fsck -fy /dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0: 59084/33292288 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 3465123/133169152 blocks
root@pve:~# resize2fs /dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0 20G
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0 to 5242880 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0 is now 5242880 (4k) blocks long.

root@pve:~# lvreduce -L 20G /dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0
  WARNING: Reducing active logical volume to 20.00 GiB.
  THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
Do you really want to reduce pve/vm-103-disk-0? [y/n]: y
  Size of logical volume pve/vm-103-disk-0 changed from 508.00 GiB (130048 extents) to 20.00 GiB (5120 extents).
  Logical volume pve/vm-103-disk-0 successfully resized.
```

Then just update the LXC config file to reflect the new size.

Comment: Perhaps superfluous, but the LXC config is in `/etc/pve/lxc/103.conf`, with the line `rootfs: local-lvm:vm-103-disk-0,size=508G` being the one to update (to `size=20G` in this case)

Answer (score 0):

since I was also stuck at this place many times and @ThisGuy's solution did not work, I used an alternative way.

**Warning: If you mess this up, your might overflow your created volume! LXC does not like this!**

1. stop the container
2. edit /etc/pve/lxc/XXX.conf
3. change the disk size for your mount point to something different (this will be used in step 5 by Proxmox to create the actual volume)
4. backup your LXC
5. restore your LXC